# Starting with Lightweight Modular Staging

Tags: scala

I am trying to start experimenting with [Lightweight Modular Staging](http://scala-lms.github.io/),
but their web page lacks a good simple "test" example showing everything from start to end, which would test that everything is installed and set up properly. As a result I am struggling doing just that. I am trying to mimic the content which I found in the test-src subdirectories of the LMS core.

So far I have done the following:

- cloned and installed the [LMS core](https://github.com/TiarkRompf/virtualization-lms-core) from github
- installed the [SBT tool](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) as requested
- installed the [virtualized scala](https://github.com/namin/scala/tree/topic-virt) from github

Then I tried creating a new SBT project, containing:

the configuration file **build.sbt**:

```
name := "lms-tutorial"

scalaOrganization := "org.scala-lang.virtualized"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "EPFL" %% "lms" % "0.3-SNAPSHOT"

scalacOptions += "-Yvirtualize"
```

And a simple program **src/main/scala/hw.scala**:

```
package scala.virtualization.lms
package epfl

import common._

object Hi {
     def snippet(x: Rep[Int]) = {
          def compute(b: Boolean): Rep[Int] = {
               // the if is executed in the first stage
               if (b) 1 else x
          }
          compute(true)+compute(1==1)
     }

     def main(args: Array[String]) =
         println("Hello World!")
}
```

But I can't make it compile. I get the following error:

```
[error] ....../src/main/scala/hw.scala:22: not found: type Rep
[error]       def compute(b: Boolean): Rep[Int] = {
[error]                                ^
[error] ....../src/main/scala/hw.scala:21: not found: type Rep
[error] def snippet(x: Rep[Int]) = {
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

The 'Rep' is the basic construct of LMS and I believe it should be imported from the `common._` but somehow it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The abstract type member `Rep[T]` is declared inside the trait [`Base`](https://github.com/TiarkRompf/virtualization-lms-core/blob/delite-develop/src/common/Base.scala). In order to use the `Rep[T]` types you need to write your programs inside the mix-in composition that contains the `Base` trait.

The easiest way to start using LMS is to follow the [LMS tutorial](http://scala-lms.github.io/pldi2013/index.html) from PLDI 2013.